# How to create setup page in NuGet package for allowing user to change some variable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nuget

I plan to create some [NuGet](http://nuget.org/) package that adds some library and some new controller to current project. I want to dynamically create the name of new controller and other related files.

Is it possible to do that just like setup page that occur when we try to install program?

- If it doesn't possible, how to create new command in NuGet package console for doing this.

**Thanks,**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a setup dialog might be a bit involved.  I am not sure if you would need to write a plugin or what.  If you simply want to automate the creation of files as templates, you should look into [Custom Mvc Scaffolding](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/04/07/mvcscaffolding-creating-custom-scaffolders/)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.  I am saying your package would be dependent on the scaffolding. Also, when someone downloads your package they would also get the Powershell scripts installed.